# how to add custom css to library

Tags: css

I am trying to change the width of arrows in a bootstrap carousel. I have worked out that I need to change the width of the carousel.scss. However this is an external library and the css that I have tried (below) doesn't work. I have looked at many examples but I don't know how to incorporate it into my work. I would really appreciate someones help, or even a link to another question that looks like this problem. Thanks

CSS

```
 .modal-body  {
padding:15px, 8%;
}
```

HTML

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>Trip Guider</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800'
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic'
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

 <!-- Plugin CSS -->
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
 <link href="./css/creative.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 </head>
```

style.css is the custom css file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to add a new stylesheet to your project called "CustomStyles.css". Add your override code to this stylesheet.

Provided you call your stylesheet as the last stylesheet on the page then the styles in "CustomStyles.css" should override the default bootstrap behaviour by default. If it still causes an issue it is possible to force your style to take precedence by marking it as !Important (shown below) but this shouldn't be necessary.

When loading your page after making this change be sure to reload the page emptying cache (ctrl f5) to make sure the original style isn't cached in your local browser.

```
 .modal-body  {
     padding:15px, 8% !Important;
 }
```

---- Result of chat conversation ------

In essence this solution works fine for overriding styles. In this instance though the wrong style was being overridden. The particular problem was resolved by inserting the following into the new stylesheet.

```
.carousel-control-prev {
    left: -50px;
}
.carousel-control-next {
    right: -50px;
}
```

Comment: I have added a custom style sheet and I have put the custom css file below the library but this doesn't seem to work

Comment: Please could you post your HTML Head Section and also the Custom Css File? - It would also be useful to see the control in your HTML that you are trying to apply the style to.

Comment: I have added the html

Comment: do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: Your jQuery UI styles are still coming after your custom styles, i'd move them higher up so they come before your own styles. (Not convinced this is the issue though.

Did you try the important flag?

Finally if you also post your custom stylesheet I should have enough to be able to recreate your problem and i'll work out what the problem is for you - or is the only thing in your custom style the .model-body override?

Comment: i changed that but there is no change. If we could start a chat i could send you all the css, the file will be too big to send in a comment

Comment: How do I start a chat? I'm knew to answering questions on stackoverflow - lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166631/discussion-between-ol12-9-and-steve-westgarth).